# Sphinx Query Language vs API - efficiency and use in production

Tags: php, python, sphinx

Sphinx search allows using API client or MYSQL Client.

API is implemented for many languages but when you download source you may see that comment (for example in php and python client)

```
//                          WARNING
// We strongly recommend you to use SphinxQL instead of the API
```

Does it mean that SphinxQL is more efficient?

Are there any contraindication against using API apart from it's design? In my opinion this API is really hard to understand for new developers and is more difficult to use than query language.

But are there any advantages of using SpinxQL instead of API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage is, can do more via SphinxQL than via the now outdated API. And its usable anywhere that has a mysql client driver - doesn't need a port of the API client to the specific language. (and the client doesnt need to be updated as you updarte sphinx)

Things like updating Real-Time (RT) indexes is only available via SphinxQL. UDFs care only installable via QL. There are plenty of smaller things too (specific functions, and options like GROUP-N)

There is a handful of things that are slightly more *efficient* via the API (eg bulk UpdateAttributes, and setOverride) - but even then are POSSIBLE via SphinxQL.